# Seed only when nothing is being downloaded in transmissoin bittorrent

Tags: router, bittorrent, transmission, bittorrent-sync

A transmission torrent app running on a router.
How to set transmission, so that it only seeds (uploads) when nothing is being downloaded ?

Reason: Download speed fall big time, if uploads are enabled simultaneously with downloads.

Comment: Just throttle your upload bandwidth. Most clients let you limit how fast they will upload at so watch your uploads, see what speed they go at and then limit your client to about 75% of that speed. That should maintain a "usable" connection while fairly sharing what you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with these commands.
But you should note, that if these commands are not directed towards a specific torrent i believe it applies the settings globally on all active torrents.

You didn't state if you were using the GUI or the CLI.

I haven't used the transmission remote GUI, so you are on your own there.

(I'm assuming these settings are also found there)

**-Bh** --bandwidth-high
    Give this torrent first chance at available bandwidth

**-Bn** --bandwidth-normal
    Give this torrent the bandwidth left over by high priority torrents

**-Bl** --bandwidth-low
    Give this torrent the bandwidth left over by high and normal priority torrents

I would personally set any active, or long term seed to the lowest priority. that way it wont mess with you while downloading new stuff.

You can also set limits by time of day, not sure if that would help you or not.

**-AS** --no-alt-speed
    Don't use the alternate Limits.

**-asd** --alt-speed-downlimit *limit*
    Limit the alternate download speed to limit kilobytes per second.

**-asu** --alt-speed-uplimit *limit*
    Limit the alternate upload speed to limit kilobytes per second.
**-asc** --alt-speed-scheduler
    Use the scheduled on/off times.

**-ASC** --no-alt-speed-scheduler
    Don't use the scheduled on/off days and times.

**--alt-speed-time-begin** *time*
    Time to start using the alt speed limits (in hhmm).

**--alt-speed-time-end** *time*
    Time to stop using the alt speed limits (in hhmm).

**--alt-speed-days** *days*
    Set the number of days on which to enable the speed scheduler, using a list such as "2,4-6".

i have also looked for a similar feature for transmission and found nothing, but in the end setting priority worked out well.

hopefully this info helps you.

https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/transmission-cli/transmission-remote.1.en.html